# How to share common code across Java classes

Tags: java

I have those Java classes:

```java
public class Item {
    String name;
    int price;
    int weight;

    public Item(String name, int price, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Sword extends Item {
    int damage;
    int speed;

    public Sword(String name, int price, int weight, int damage, int speed) {
        super(name, price, weight);
        this.damage = damage;
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

```java
public class HasDurability {
    int current_durability;
    int max_durability;

    public HasDurability(int durability) {
        this.max_durability = durability;
        this.current_durability = durability;
    }

    public void damage(int damage) {
        current_durability -= damage;
    }
}
```

I want to share code from HasDurability class with Sword but not with Item.

Edit: Also I want to share HasDurability with other classes like Armor.

I can only extend one class. How do I share code from Item and from HasDurability to Sword class?

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine to create a class HasDurability attribute inside the class Sword?

Comment: Also I want to share HasDurability with other classes like Armor.

Comment: then you can just create a HasDurability attribute inside that class too I guess.

Comment: @maciej   Sharing code means extending attributes of the objects. If you’re going to extend sword, then items would automatically be extended as base class and if you will extend Item, then sword attributes won’t be extended to your HasDurabilty class. This the parent child relationships. You can’t have sword without having item unless you create sword without having Items of it’s parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems more like you should just have hierarchy like this

```
public class Item

public class DurableItem extends Item

public class Sword extends DurableItem
```

Unless there is something which can have durability that is not an item, which doesn't sound likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse code by either composition or inheritance. The first way is you instantiate a class you want to use the methods of in the "extending" class and you use it like that. The other way is you extend the class.
So either you do

```
Item item = new Item(name, price, weight);
HasDurability hasDurability = new HasDurability(durability);
```

in the class you want those classes to be used, or you extend a common superclass.
You could create an abstract superclass and provide shared methods if the need arises.

I also recommend you rename the HasDurability class to just Durability, because the "hasSomething" or "isSomething" is usually used for boolean values like:

```
boolean hasFur = false;// imagine you have an animal class and you wanna know if the animal has fur or not
```